# How to limit panning distance in react three fiber MapControls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, drei

I‘m using `React Three Fiber` and `drei`. I'm wondering how to limit the maximum panning distance with the `MapControls`.
There are some solutions online on how to archive it with plain `three.js` but nothing using the `MapControls` or `OrbitControls` from `drei` and `r3f`.

I tried this but once I reach the limit the camera glitches weirdly.

```
function Controls() {
  const { camera } = useThree();

  useFrame(() => {
    camera.position.x = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(camera.position.x, -90, 90)
    camera.position.y = THREE.MathUtils.clamp(camera.position.y, -90, 90)
  })
  
  return (
    <MapControls />
  )
}
```

Thanks for your help

Alexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/disable-a-pan-axis-in-orbitcontrols/31277/6) answer a solution would be to create a custom `'Controls'` component looking like this.

```
const Controls = () => {
  const { camera } = useThree()
  const controlsRef = useRef()    

  useEffect(() => {
    controlsRef.current.addEventListener('change', function () {
      if (this.target.y < -10) {
        this.target.y = -10
        camera.position.y = -10
      } else if (this.target.y > 10) {
        this.target.y = 10
        camera.position.y = 10
      }
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <MapControls ref={controlsRef} enableZoom={false} enableRotate={false} />
  )
}
```

Which can then be used as a child to the `Canvas` component.

```
<Canvas>
  <Controls />
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on the answers above

```
  const { camera, size } = useThree();

  const limitPanningDistance = useCallback(
    (e?: THREE.Event) => {
      // 704.5 102
      // 1056.75 320

      // Returns the drag container width and height
      const [w, h] = [1920, 1080]

      const pan = (w * camera.zoom - size.width) / 2 / camera.zoom;
      const vertical = (h * camera.zoom - size.height) / 2 / camera.zoom;

      // console.log('pan vertical', pan, vertical);

      const maxX = pan;
      const minX = -pan;
      const maxY = vertical;
      const minY = -vertical;
      const x = e?.target.target.x;
      const y = e?.target.target.y;
      if (x < minX || x > maxX) {
        e?.target.target.setX(x < minX ? minX : maxX);
        camera.position.setX(x < minX ? minX : maxX);
      }
      if (y < minY || y > maxY) {
        e?.target.target.setY(y < minY ? minY : maxY);
        camera.position.setY(y < minY ? minY : maxY);
      }
    },
    [camera.zoom, size]
  );
```

```
      <MapControls
        enableRotate={false}
        minZoom={1}
        maxZoom={2}
        onChange={(e) => {
          // console.log(e?.target);
          limitPanningDistance(e);
        }}
        makeDefault
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with using `onChange` property of `MapControls`.

Controls component:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { MapControls } from '@react-three/drei'
import { useThree } from '@react-three/fiber'

const Controls = () => {
  const { camera } = useThree()
  const cameraLastPosition = useRef({
    x: camera.position.x,
    y: camera.position.y,
  })

  return (
    <MapControls
      onChange={(e) => {
        const maxX = 90
        const minX = -90
        const maxY = 90
        const minY = -90
        const x = e?.target.target.x
        const y = e?.target.target.y

        if (x < minX || x > maxX) {
          e?.target.target.setX(x < minX ? minX : maxX)
          camera.position.setX(cameraLastPosition.current.x)
        }
        if (y < minY || y > maxY) {
          e?.target.target.setY(y < minY ? minY : maxY)
          camera.position.setY(cameraLastPosition.current.y)
        }
        cameraLastPosition.current.x = camera.position.x
        cameraLastPosition.current.y = camera.position.y
      }}
    />
  )
}

export default Controls
```

Import that component and use it in your `Canvas`:

```
<Canvas>
  <Controls />
</Canvas>
```